# deleting first line of an xml file in Perl

Tags: xml, perl

Hi I have an XML file which I want to remove first line of it using Perl and replace it with only one word. Would you please let me know how one could manage it?

Fro example, let' we have an XML file which includes some lines as:

```
<SquishReport version="2.1" xmlns="http://www.froglogic.com/XML2">
<test name="test">
.
.
.
```

which after removing and adding the desired line I would have:

```
<SquishReport>
<test name="test">
.
.
```

Comment: You want to delete the root node? That sound like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to accomplish? Please give some (complete) samples if input/output XML.

Comment: @Sobrique Please see the edited version

Comment: OK, I understand the question a bit better, and have answered accordingly. However I think this is still an XY problem - I would question why you need to delete the root node attributes?

Comment: Because when I have root node with attribute then the code could not read children, otherwise it works very fine.

Comment: Which code? Because chances are that's not doing XML properly, and that's where your problem actually lies.

Comment: Please take a look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370690/perl-could-not-read-the-xml-files

Comment: Yes, "In my code". What are you using "in your code" that can't handle well formed XML? Because that's bad news for all concerned.

Comment: XPath 1 and namespaces don't go very well together :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm):

Replace "root element + attributes" with just "root element":

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
 
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parse ( \*DATA );
$twig -> root -> del_atts;
$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');
$twig -> print;

__DATA__
<SquishReport version="2.1" xmlns="http://www.froglogic.com/XML2">
<test name="test"> </test>
</SquishReport>
```

Prints:

```
<SquishReport>
  <test name="test"> </test>
</SquishReport>
```

Note -

```
$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');
```

Can change file content - from the docs on `XML::Twig`:

> WARNING: this option leaves the document well-formed but might make it invalid (not conformant to its DTD).

So turning off pretty printing if that's a concern would be the appropriate choice.

Comment: `$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');` can modify the file. Best not to use it "by default".

Comment: `keep_spaces => 1` in the `new` will leave all whitespace untouched (except for line returns in attribute values which are normalized by the parser)

Comment: I haven't been tripped up by it yet, but I'll amend the answer.