# ERROR: XML::LibXML->load: specify location, string, or IO at 8.pl line 144

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I am using the first answer to [*Extracting data from an XML document that uses namespaces*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370690/extracting-data-from-an-xml-document-that-uses-namespaces) to create an XML file using Perl.

Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use XML::LibXML;
use XML::Simple;
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext qw( );
use XML::Writer;
use IO::File;
use File::Copy;
use List::Util;

###****************************************************************

my $dir   = "D:/XML";
my $count = 0;
my $entry;
my $case;
my $xmlFile;
my $case_entry;
my $entry_name;
my $result;
my $value_result;
my $value_result_end;
my $type_result;
my @testFile = <*.xml>;
my $arrSize  = @testFile;
my @testCase;
my $testCasesize = @testCase;
my @test_result;
my $test_resultsize = @test_result;

#################################################################################

sub WriteXML {

    chdir( $dir ) or die "Couldn't go inside $dir directory, $!";
    opendir( my $dh, $dir ) or die "$0: $dir: $!\n";

    ###****************************************************************

    my $output = IO::File->new( ">test.xml" );
    my $writer = XML::Writer->new( OUTPUT => $output );
    $writer->xmlDecl( 'utf-8' );
    $writer->pi( 'xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl"   href="file:///D:/XML/xml2html_new.xslt"' );
    $writer->startTag( "Summary" );
    $writer->characters( "\n" );
    $writer->startTag( "test", "name" => "Test_tst" );
    $writer->characters( "\n" );

    ###****************************************************************

    my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
    $xpc->registerNs( sr => 'http://www.froglogic.com/XML2' );

    my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $testFile[0] );

    for $entry ( $xpc->findnodes( '/sr:SquishReport/sr:test/sr:test', $doc ) ) {
        $testCase[$count] = $entry->getAttribute( 'name' );
        $count = $count + 1;
    }

    for $case ( @testCase ) {

        $writer->startTag( "test", "name" => "$case" );
        $writer->characters( "\n" );

        for $xmlFile ( @testFile ) {

            my $docFile   = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $xmlFile );
            my $attribute = qq(\@name="$case");
            my $num       = 0;

            for $case_entry ( $xpc->findnodes( "//sr:SquishReport/sr:test/sr:test[$attribute]/sr:verification/sr:result", $docFile ) ) {

                $type_result = $case_entry->findvalue( '@type' );

                if ( ( $type_result eq "FAIL" ) || ( $type_result eq "ERROR" ) || ( $type_result eq "FATAL" ) ) {
                    $value_result = "NotOK";
                }
                elsif ( ( $type_result eq "PASS" ) ) {
                    $value_result = "OK";
                }
                elsif ( $type_result eq "WARNING" ) {
                    $value_result = "WARR";
                }
                else {
                    $value_result = "UNDEF";
                }

                $test_result[$num] = $value_result;
                $num = $num + 1;
            }

            if ( @test_result == grep { $_ eq "OK" } @test_result ) {
                $value_result_end = "OK";
            }
            elsif ( grep { $_ eq 'NotOK' } @test_result ) {
                $value_result_end = "NotOK";
            }
            elsif ( grep { ( $_ eq 'WARR' ) } @test_result ) {
                $value_result_end = "WARR";
            }
            else {
                $value_result_end = "UNDEF";
            }

            # print "$value_result_end";
            $writer->startTag( "result", "state" => "$value_result_end" );
            $writer->characters( "\n" );
            $writer->startTag( "description", "href" => "$xmlFile" );
            $writer->characters( "\n" );
            $writer->startTag( "description" );
            $writer->characters( "\n" );
            $writer->cdata( $xmlFile );
            $writer->characters( "\n" );
            $writer->endTag( "description" );
            $writer->endTag( "description" );
            $writer->endTag( "result" );
        }

        $writer->endTag( "test" );
        $writer->characters( "\n" );
    }

    ###****************************************************************

    $writer->endTag( "test" );
    $writer->characters( "\n" );
    $writer->endTag( "Summary" );
    $writer->end();
    $output->close();
}

###****************************************************************

&WriteXML( $dir );
system( "summary.xml" );
```

As it is mentioned, the directory for reading XML files is another drive (here `D:\`). If I put all XML files in the same folder where Perl code is then works great but otherwise I have the error:

> Could not create file parser context for file "test.xml": Inappropriate I/O control operation at test.pl line 46.

Would you please let me know where I am missing something that causes error?

Comment: Re "XML::LibXML->load: specify location, string, or IO at 8.pl line 144.", There aren't 144 lines in that program. Please post the output you actually got!!!!

Comment: @ikegami Now I have added the whole code!!

Comment: You made things worse! Use the *minimal* amount of code to demonstrate your problem, and your output still doesn't match up with the code you posted.

Comment: There was an edition by another person and then it is not the exact line which I have written.

Answer (score -1):

#### Update

I apologise. I thought I had answered this question since you updated it with your full code. I guess I typed it up and discarded it by mistake

The problem is that the line

```
my @testFile = <*.xml>
```

is executed *before* your `chdir` to the directory. To fix it, just move that line to *after* the `chdir` within the subroutine

And while we're at it, you are passing the directory path to the subroutine but not using it. You should write something like

```
my ($dir) = @_;
chdir $dir;
my @testFile = <*.xml>;
```

You should also `use autodie` at the top of the program, which will automatically catch any errors from file IO like `open`, `close`, `chdir` etc. Without you having to code `or die $!` on each one

#### Original response

> If I put all XML files in the same folder as perl code is then works great

For a number of reasons, I don't think the code you have posted can work at all, regardless of where you place the XML data file. Here are some things you need to fix

- You don't `use XML::Writer` anywhere
- You don't call `WriteXML`
- The error is on line 144 of your program, but that code is only thirty lines long
- You open `test.xml` for output but never close it, so the data is probably not written to the file before you read it with `XML::LibXML`
- The data you are writing is just `<Summary><test name="test">` with no closing tags, so it would be an invalid XML file
- Even if your data *was* written and the elements were closed properly, your code then looks for the XPath `/sr:SquishReport/sr:test/sr:test` which is nothing like the data in the file so it will fail

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, I am sure it works fine and now you may find the whole code as edited version!!